# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'No Firebase namespace specified.'

Tags: firebase

In response to the following Firebase Objective-C/Xcode code:

```
Firebase *myRootRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://home.FirebaseTest.firebaseio.com"];
```

note: home.FirebaseTest is my Firebase app name (see link below)
https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html

I receive the following exception/error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'No Firebase namespace
>   specified.', reason: 'No Firebase namespace found for input: '

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: what are you pretending with `https://home.FirebaseTest.firebaseio.com`?

Comment: I edited my question in reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that your problem relies on your URL.

Didn't get how you named your project `home.FirebaseTest` and what this `home.` stands for.

But you can get the proper url going to firebase console and on "Database" tab you should be able to see your firebaseio.com url.

For example in an app called "myfirebasetest" it would be

```
https://myfirebasetest.firebaseio.com
```

[image]

On legacy UI it is the url you use to access the console.

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Keep in mind OP might also be using a project from the legacy firebase console (accessed through `https://myfirebasetest.firebaseio.com`, instead of `https://console.firebase.google.com`).

Comment: Thanks it worked, I was not aware of that URL location , by mistake i had put app bundle name !!